# understanding set of controllable state for switched system

Tags: control-theory

With the reference of this question: [Understanding Definition of Switching Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605955/understanding-definition-of-switching-sequence)

Could anyone make me understand Theorem 1 from the same article? why such expression for controllable set? I have understood the lemma  1.
Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: how $x_f$ can be written in that form?

Comment: I think I have to understand this first https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607808/understanding-solution-of-state-equation/2608245#2608245